# Ansible "Failed to connect to the host via ssh

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible, virtualbox, permission-denied

I am working with VirtualBox, Vagrant and Ansible. 
It worked fine until I ran

```
ssh vagrant@10.10.10.10
```

and got the following output:

```
The authenticity of host '10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is
SHA256:IIbQq8qenKqUEpurYCMbbaRBCHXEgWK4Br7KSusmyw4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I typed "yes", and since then every time I type `vagrant provision`, I keep getting:

```
fatal: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '10.10.10.10' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied ().\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

I then removed the generated key from `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: what happens, when you run `vagrant ssh` from within the same folder that holds your `Vagrantfile`?

Comment: I can ssh into vm just fine, but I cannot provision it.

Comment: Also, I tried to play with different versions of VirtualBox, Vagrant, and Ansible uninstalling and installing it back, but this error is not going away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a ton of time searching for the answer I found the solution that worked for me. I added the following few lines to my Vagrantfile and reloaded vm

```
ansible.raw_arguments = [
"--private-key=~/path/to/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key"
]
```